# Finding the Occurrence of a Pattern in a Data Block using C

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out finding the occurrence of a set of numbers in a data block without using arrays. Right now my issue is that everytime it finds the first number in the pattern it assumes the whole pattern is right. I am having trouble trying to go through the whole pattern using patternLength in the data block before assuming it is right. For example is the pattern I want to find over and over again is 12 14 3C 48. Everytime is sees the number 12 it says it is the whole pattern.

```
uint32_t findOccurrencesOfPattern(uint32_t *const pOffsets,
                                  const uint8_t *const blockAddress,
                                  uint32_t blockLength,
                                  const uint8_t *const pPattern,
                                  uint8_t patternLength) {
  uint32_t bytesRead = 0;
  int count = 0;
  int length = 0;
  // const char* c = ((const char *)&pPattern);
  while (bytesRead < blockLength) {
    if (*(blockAddress + bytesRead) == *pPattern) {
      *(pOffsets + count) = bytesRead;
      count++;
    }
    patternLength--;
    bytesRead++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your results unless I know the values of the args to findOccurrencesOfPattern

Answer (score 0):

You will need to turn the `if()` statement (which presently check only the first byte) into a `for()` loop to iterate over `patternLength`-worth of bytes.