# Finding repeated occurrences of bytes in C

Tags: c

I am trying to modify a function so that it can traverse through a block of memory and find repeated sections of bytes. The current function I have written can find a single one, but I think I am having trouble with my pointers and logic.

Here is my original function to find a single byte. It returns the number of times it is found and the offsets are stored in pOffsets:

```
//pOffsets points to an array large enough to hold the results
//blockAddress points to the first byte of the memory region
//blockLength is the number of bytes in the memory region
//Byte is the value to be searched for
//maxBytes is the maximum number of bytes that are to be copied

uint32_t findOccurrencesOfByte(uint32_t* const pOffsets,
                           const uint8_t* const blockAddress, uint32_t blockLength,
                           uint8_t Byte, uint32_t maxBytes) {
    uint32_t count, pos;
    count = 0;
    for (pos = 0; count < maxBytes && pos < blockLength; pos++) {
        if (*(blockAddress + pos) == Byte) {
            *(pOffsets + count) = pos;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This is the piece of code I am trying to change to find a **section** of bytes:

```
//pOffsets points to an array of dimension at least 256
//blockAddress points to the first byte of the memory region
//blockLength is number of bytes in the memory region
//pPattern points to a copy of the pattern that is to be found
//patternLength is the number of bytes in the target pattern

uint32_t findOccurrencesOfPattern(uint32_t* const pOffsets,
                              const uint8_t* const blockAddress, uint32_t blockLength,
                              const uint8_t* const pPattern, uint8_t patternLength) {
    uint32_t count, pos, i;
    count = 0;
    for (pos = 0; pos < blockLength; pos++) {
        for (i = 0; patternLength != 0; patternLength--) {
            if (*(blockAddress + pos + i) == *pPattern) {
                *(pOffsets + count) = pos;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Do you actually need to write that function? Standard C library provides most of the building blocks for this.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately...

Comment: `for (i = 0; patternLength != 0; patternLength--) {` — decreasing the function parameter to zero is a bad, bad, bad idea.  Or, at the least, I wonder what you're doing there, and I'm deeply suspicious it is part of your problem.  It would be cleaner to replace `*(blockAddress + pos + i)` with `blockAddress[pos + i]`; likewise, to replace `*(pOffsets + count) = pos;
                count++;` with `pOffsets[count++] = pos;`.

Comment: I guess that's part of my question. I'm essentially trying to create a block of bytes to compare to pPattern... unless there is a more logical way of doing it. I figured I would add bytes to this block according to the pattern length (ex. 5 bytes). I don't know how to lump those multiple bytes together though to get to that point of comparison.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60959051/finding-the-occurrence-of-a-pattern-in-a-data-block-using-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you are trying to do is to match the pattern starting from every point in your memory block. Decreasing `patternLength` makes no sense, since you will need that length multiple times.

```c
uint32_t findOccurrencesOfPattern(uint32_t* const pOffsets,
                              const uint8_t* const blockAddress, uint32_t blockLength,
                              const uint8_t* const pPattern, uint8_t patternLength) {
    uint32_t count, pos, i;
    count = 0;
    for (pos = 0; pos < blockLength - patternLength; pos++) {
        uint8_t ok = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < patternLength; i++) {
            if (*(blockAddress + pos + i) != *(pPattern + i)) {
                ok = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ok)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Also, you don't want to increase the count inside the inner for, because you would be counting every matched byte (even those in partial matches).

You should stop the iteration at `blockLength - patternLength`, because after that you definitely cannot find any other match.

And the approach should be: assume that you find a match (`ok = 1` initially). Then check if it is so. When you find a contradiction, say it is not ok and break the loop (you already determined that it's not a match).

Comment: This worked for me! I added the *(pOffsets + count) = pos; line of code with count++ to assign the offsets. The boolean flag was very helpful to find a whole section instead of the just the first byte.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing an array of pointers to the start of match locations.  The input type should be uint8_t**.  uint8_t** is a pointer to uint8_t* which is the address of the match location.

You do not need to have `const` twice in the same input parameter.

I also agree with the comment above that index with [ ] makes for more readable code.

The following should work for you.

```
#define MAX_MATCHES 2

const uint8_t  data[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7,6,4,5,6 };
const uint8_t  pattern[] = { 4,5,6 };

const uint8_t * startAddress[MAX_MATCHES];

uint32_t findOccurrencesOfPattern(const uint8_t** matchAddress,
    const uint8_t* blockAddress, uint32_t blockLength,
    const uint8_t* pPattern, uint8_t patternLength)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= blockLength - patternLength; i++)
    {
        bool match = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < patternLength; j++)
        {
            if (blockAddress[i + j] != pPattern[j])
            {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (match)
        {
            match = false;
            matchAddress[count] = &blockAddress[i];
            count++;

            //Don't look for overlapping patterns
            i += patternLength;  

            //Don't overrun matchAdress
            if (count >= MAX_MATCHES) 
            {
                return count;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Test Function

```
int main()
{
    uint32_t count = findOccurrencesOfPattern(startAddress, data, sizeof(data), pattern, sizeof(pattern));
}
```